# Strip all characters except digits in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, numbers, filtering

My users are giving these inputs

`123 - 4567 - 5665`

`123124-124325`

But I need to submit them in form only with digits. Also I can't expect users to do it for me by giving them alerts. That would be too inconvenient for them.

So result for in DB should be this `12345675665`

I'm using ruby on rails 4.2.

What filter should I use and where?

Comment: thanks for it. But where should I put this code? `def raw_phonenumber
  self.phonenumber
end
def raw_phonenumber=(s)
  self.phonenumber=s.gsub(/\D/, '')
end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_validation :tweak_my_attribute

  def tweak_my_attribute
     self.my_attribute = my_attribute.to_s.gsub(/\D/, '')
  end

end
```

Comment: Your answer is correct and since it will only be handling this per instance performance is not a huge factor but `String#scan` actually performs faster in these cases e.g. `my_attribute.to_s.scan(/\d+/).join`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. Answer accepted!

Comment: @engineersmnky I've seen that mentioned before, but I wonder if `\d+` is the real key this time? Or am I doing my benchmark wrong? I grabbed about 25K phone numbers out of one of my tables. (I got curious) https://gist.github.com/phallstrom/c03bd7a1182d5ebdcb18

Comment: @engineersmnky In several tests I ran `scan(/\d+/).join` was a little bit slower (roughly 15%) than `gsub(/\D+/, '')`. The method using scan must create a new Array before it creates a new string, so it likely uses more memory, too, although I did not specifically test for that. As always, performance on systems varies greatly, so it is important to benchmark.

Comment: Phillip Hallstrom & @WizardofOgz I feel like this must be a system (and clearly ruby version) dependent item as my benchmarking comes out as I described.[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/engineersmnky/197e9316bd669cdedcd8) I guess that's why it is important to benchmark on the system that will actually be running the application or code. In this case though the difference is extremely minimal even over 100_000 iterations so my comment could just be "You could also do it this way" :)

Comment: @engineersmnky It's interesting how much slower your tests ran under Ruby 2.1.5 than they did under 1.9.3. In case you are interested here are the results of your tests on my system (OSX 10.11) with Ruby 2.2.2 [Gist](https://gist.github.com/WizardOfOgz/e52bdda95c2154860efc).